# Using a downloaded shapefile in ggplot2 and R, readOGR error

Tags: r, rgdal, ggplot2, rstudio

I am having trouble taking a downloaded shapefile and using it in R and `{ggplot2}`. The online instructions (like [this one](https://r-graph-gallery.com/168-load-a-shape-file-into-r.html)) use code that have the function `readOGR()`. When I use `readOGR()`, I get several errors, including that the file cannot be read and that the function requires support from `{terra}` and `{sf}` packages.

I get the following message when installing `{rgdal}` (what is used in every thread on this):

"Please note that rgdal will be retired during 2023,
plan transition to sf/stars/terra functions using GDAL and PROJ
at your earliest convenience. 
See https://r-spatial.org/r/2022/04/12/evolution.html and [https://github.com/r-spatial/evolution"](https://github.com/r-spatial/evolution%22)

From what I understand, I need to read it in R and then it can be used in `{ggplot2}`. I am just so confused on this now that it isn't working.

This is the example of the code I found in another thread:

```r
shapefile <- readOGR("/Downloads", "Zone.shp")
shapefile_df <- fortify(shapefile)
```

Comment: Please consider transitioning to `{sf}` and have a look at `sf::st_read()`, see [Spatial Data Science](https://r-spatial.org/book/07-Introsf.html#reading-and-writing) for examples.

Answer (score 2):

@Spacedman already pointed this out. That manual is out of date, just use `sf`. See here an updated version of the webpage but switching to `sf`:

```r
# Download the shapefile

tempzip <- tempfile(fileext = ".zip")

download.file("http://thematicmapping.org/downloads/TM_WORLD_BORDERS_SIMPL-0.3.zip" , 
              destfile=tempzip)

# Unzip this file. You can do it with R (as below)

unzip(tempzip, exdir = tempdir())

#  -- > You now have 4 files. One of these files is a .shp file! (TM_WORLD_BORDERS_SIMPL-0.3.shp)

# Read this shape file with the sf library. 
library(sf)

my_sf <- st_read(file.path(tempdir(), "TM_WORLD_BORDERS_SIMPL-0.3.shp"))

# Basic plot of this shape file:
par(mar=c(0,0,0,0))
plot(st_geometry(my_sf), col="#f2f2f2", bg="skyblue", lwd=0.25, border=0 )
```

[image]

```r
# ggplot2 handles 'sf' natively

# Plot it
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(my_sf) +
  geom_sf(fill="#69b3a2", color="white") +
  theme_void()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-06-01 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: FYI, if you set the URL as a variable (eg., `url <- "http://thematicmapping.org/BORDERS.zip"`) then you can simply use `basename(url)` for the `destfile` argument.

Answer (score 1):

Any online instructions that use the `sp` or `rgdal` packages to read spatial data (such as shapefiles) will produce that warning and will stop working entirely by the end of the year for up-to-date versions of R, as stated in the warning.

You should look for information on using the `sf` package instead. https://r.geocompx.org/ is a good resource.